# Speed of matrix multiplication with Octave

Tags: numpy, matrix, octave

I was curious just how fast matrix multiplication is with Octave 3.8.2, so I used the following code to time the multiplication of two 5000X5000 matrices:

```
X = rand(5000,5000);
Y = rand(5000,5000);
BEFORE = time();
Z = X*Y;
AFTER = time();
disp(AFTER - BEFORE);
```

The result was about 1 minute on average.  Using almost identical code, I did the same computation in Python with numpy matrices.  It took about 7.5 s.

I was surprised by these results, because I was under the impression that Octave is highly optimized for matrix computations.  Are my results typical?  Do people generally prefer Python over Octave when it comes to large scale matrix computations?

EDIT: Here is the numpy code...

```
X = numpy.matrix(numpy.random.rand(5000,5000))
Y = numpy.matrix(numpy.random.rand(5000,5000))
BEFORE = time.process_time()
Z = X*Y;
AFTER = time.process_time()
print(AFTER - BEFORE)
```

Comment: Show us your `numpy` code.  It's impossible to tell why there's a huge time differential without it.

Comment: BTW, I ran this code in MATLAB, and this runs in 3.32 seconds.  I used `tic/toc`.  My configuration is MATLAB R2013a in Mac OS 10.10.5 with 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: Also depends on which compiler you used to compile NumPy (it's C and Fortran code under the hood) and which compiler you used for your blas/lapack/atlas

Comment: I believe I am using Cython.  I just downloaded Anaconda3, so I am using whatever comes with that.

Comment: octave-3.6.4.exe:1> x = rand(5000, 5000);
octave-3.6.4.exe:2> y = rand(5000, 5000);
octave-3.6.4.exe:3> before = time();
octave-3.6.4.exe:4> z = x*y;
octave-3.6.4.exe:5> after = time();
octave-3.6.4.exe:6> disp(after-before);
 16.258
octave-3.6.4.exe:7>

Comment: 16.258 seconds for me.  Running Windows 7 64 bit on AMD 3GHz 6 core with 8GB RAM.

Comment: So, it ran about 2 times slower than my Python code and 4 times faster than my Octave code.  I am running Windows 10 64 bit Intel i7-5500U 2.4 GHz 4 core with 8GB RAM.

Comment: @rayryeng I am fairly certain that is incorrect.  I tried using the * operator with 2 small numpy matrices, and it did perform matrix multiplication as expected.  I think you may be confusing numpy matrices with numpy arrays.

Comment: @AriHerman - You are correct.  My apologies.  I read that as `numpy` arrays, not matrices..... which brings me to another question.  Did you try using `numpy` arrays and using `numpy.dot`?

Comment: @rayryeng Using numpy arrays and numpy.dot the computation took 8.5 s.  Slightly slower than using numpy matrices.

Comment: @AriHerman - Interesting.  I'm surprised why Octave took a minute for you... especially since MATLAB and Octave use BLAS under the hood.

Comment: With octave packaged in ubuntu 14.04 LTS it take ~17sec on a machine with eight cores i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz (and enough RAM). With python, it uses a unique core (default behaviour) and it took more than five minutes...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce such bad results

```
timesum = 0
maxtime = 0
mintime = 100
for n = 1:100
  x = rand(5000,5000);
  y = rand(5000,5000);
  tic
  Z = x*y;
  tmptime = toc;
  timesum += tmptime;
  maxtime = max(maxtime, tmptime);
  mintime = min(mintime, tmptime);  
end
disp("meantime")
disp(timesum/100)
disp("maxtime")
disp(maxtime)
disp("mintime")
disp(mintime)


octave:1> test1
timesum =                    0
maxtime =                    0
mintime =                  100
meantime
    4.34704959154129
maxtime
      5.297199010849
mintime
    4.09799385070801
octave:2>
```

Octave 4.0.0 on Haswell i5 Mobile.

The result with Matlab is nearly the same

```
meantime
    4.0443

maxtime
    5.5522

mintime
    3.9679
```

That's no surprise. They are using, more or less, the same libraries.